# Got an error when post message with image on facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Please help me to solve this below error :

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
        body =     {
            error =         {
                code = 2500;
                "fbtrace_id" = "HkQ+T3pxGRU";
                message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
                type = OAuthException;
            };
        };
        code = 400;
    }, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400}
```

I got an error when posting message with image on facebook and i m using latest facebook sdk.

I'm using this below code:

```
    -(void)posting
     {
       if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]) {
         NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
         [params setObject:@"hello hii how r u " forKey:@"message"];
         [params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.img_to_share.image) forKey:@"picture"];
         [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                      parameters:params
                                      HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                               completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                   id result,
                                                   NSError *error)
          {
              if (error)
              {
                  //showing an alert for failure
                  NSLog(@"Unable to share the photo please try later.");
              }
              else
              {
                  //showing an alert for success
                  NSLog(@"Shared the photo successfully");
              }
          }];

     }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: add code for that in question.

Comment: `"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."`  is user logined to fb?

Comment: Yes, user was already logged in fb @AnilVarghese

Answer (score 0):

***Edit:***

check after adding access_token in the graph calls since the facebook-ios-sdk doesn't do this automatically.

```
[FBRequestConnection requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/me/photos?access_token=%@", FBRequestConnection.accessToken]
  andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

For more information check: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user#posts

Comment: Don't pass image data in picture parameter, just pass url for image in "picture".@Moni_BQ

Comment: Not working. App will crash if when I passed "image url "